# Prove that $P(A|B^c) \neq 1-P(A|B)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is $P(A|B^c) = 1-P(A|B)$? I do not think so. There are many examples in which this equality does not hold. But how do I prove it formally?

Comment: You only need to find one counterexample, no formal proof is needed.

Comment: The identity that you seem to have been reaching for that is actually correct is that $P(A\mid B) = 1 - P(A^c\mid B)$, totally different meaning than the identity you wrote.

Comment: No, I am not looking for that relationship. I was just trying to figure out what is the relationship between $P(A|B^c) $ and $P(A|B)$ Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove that equality never holds. For example, if $A=B^{c}$ then  equality does hold. All that you can do is to give one example where equality fails.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to find a general relationship between $P(A|B^c)$ and $P(A|B)$ that holds in any case, so that we can derive under which particular conditions fhe relationship $P(A|B^c) = 1-P(A|B)$ holds?

Comment: A general relationship between the two conditional probabilities is $P(B^{c})P(A|B^{c})=P(A)-P(B)P(A|B)$.  @Alchemy

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!